# How two completely unrelated software can affect each other in a very strange manner?

Tags: gaming

I installed an old game on my old PC and it doesn't work; its process/exe file was listed in task manager but nothing appeared on the screen.

then some time later i discovered that when some specific program was running an my pc, that game could be executed without that problem!

although i am myself a power user and also a programmer, i couldn't find the reason, and don't have any good guesses about it. i just know that when i want to run that game i should have another specific and unrelated program running.

i ask if anyone has any idea/guess about the possible reasons for this rare phenomenon!

oh and if u ask about the details/names of those programs, i am afraid of telling that, because others may think i am kidding, but i am not (please believe me!), that game is NFS2 and the other program is mysqld.exe (i said before that i am a programmer!).
I don't know how mysqld.exe (yes it is the windows version of the famous MySQL DBMS server) can affect NFS2 in such an strange manner, and my curiosity and profession don't let me to forget seeking for the answer, so i decided to take the help of others to see if someone has had a similar experience or a reasonable idea about it.

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is how Windows manages its processes. I've read that Windows treats every different app as a thread (which share the same stack) that's why, for example, CheatEngine can have access to other processes' memory.

Not like many UNIX based systems, where every process is in fact a different process that have their respective resources well delimited between each other. That's why there is no CheatEngine for Linux or only serials work for OSX's apps. And the only way one process interferes with others is with system resources, sockets and ports.

Maybe the other app is using/freeing some resources that your app needs (it could even be a singleton lock file, like when a chrome process is running and doesn't respond and so it fails to run another instance of the app).

I'm not any kind of computer guru but this is what I know based on the experience I've had so far, I'm a technician but not an engineer.